# Basic Auth with Remote URL option

Tags: basic-authentication, rundeck

I am using Remote URL option which reaches out to remote web server to retrieve needed data. Simply using this,
https://rundeck:test@myserver.com works. However, I would like to pass the password in secure way so...

- Option 1 uses 'Secure pass input' and pass is retrieved from key storage, however the password is then not added to the remote URL in
- Option 2, which uses Remote URL, https://rundeck:${option.password.value}@myserver.com. My remote servers receives the password as ${option.password.value} and not the actual password value retrieved in Option 1. I understand that Secure Remote Authentication can't be used in Options, however i don't believe I have seen restrictions on what I want to do with Secure † Password input in Rundeck's docs.

Lastly, typing in the password in Secure † Password input option does add the password to the mentioned URL above. I have tested and verified that ${option.password.value} value can be passed in a job's step, that part works. However, it does not appear to work in cascading options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rundeck has addressed this issue by providing multiple options for Remote URL, see the docs.
https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#option-model-provider

Comment: Could you add the key parts from the docs to your answer? If the link goes stale at some point in the future, just having the link makes it hard to read up on the details. (Great to see you got back to your old question, though! So many of these just end up abandoned.)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, secure options values are not expanded as a part of remote options, you can suggest it [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck) (similar to [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1354)). Alternatively, you can create a specific custom [plugin](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/12-option-values-plugins.html#option-values-plugins) for that.

Another approach is to design a workflow that uses the [HTTP Workflow Step Plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/http-step) (passing your secure password as a part of the authentication in the URL) to access the web service + [JQ Filter](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/jq-json-logfilter) to generate the desired data, then in another/step you can get that data using data variables.

Like this:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 7f34f7ff-c4a3-4616-a2aa-0df491450366
  loglevel: INFO
  name: HTTP
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - name: mypass
    secure: true
    storagePath: keys/password
    valueExposed: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - configuration:
        authentication: None
        checkResponseCode: 'false'
        method: GET
        printResponse: 'true'
        printResponseToFile: 'false'
        proxySettings: 'false'
        remoteUrl: https://user:${option.mypass}@myserver.com
        sslVerify: 'true'
        timeout: '30000'
      nodeStep: false
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            filter: .
            logData: 'true'
            prefix: result
          type: json-mapper
      type: edu.ohio.ais.rundeck.HttpWorkflowStepPlugin
    - exec: echo "name 2 is ${data.Name2}"
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 7f34f7ff-c4a3-4616-a2aa-0df491450366
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, HTTP workflow step will not work for me, here is why. My job has few options, they are cascading options and each one uses remote URL, it is designed this way so users can select, in each option, from available resources pulled real time from remote devices. Collected data from each option is then used as command line arguments is step 1 of the job which is the command step. I am considering to use http step instead of command step to ship the data to remote device for execution. Hopefully this makes sense. I will submit your suggestion as well.

Comment: The following suggestion for feature update has been opened.                                      
"Key Storage variable expansion for remote URLs for basic auth. #7091"