# Cascading Remote option values with Key Storage values

Tags: rundeck

Rundeck offers the possibility to load values of an option from a [remote url](https://docs.rundeck.com/3.4.9/manual/job-options.html#remote-option-values). 
Furthermore, the [cascading of option](https://docs.rundeck.com/3.4.9/manual/job-options.html#option-model-provider) is also implemented.

We have the use case to load static values (like environments) from a remote host.
The URL looks like the following: `https://username:password@api.local/get-environment`

If the URL is entered directly into the `Remote URL` field, everything works as expected.
But as seen in the example, the API is password protected, and we have to provide a username and password. So, it's maybe a good idea to not store the data inside the `Remote URL` field directly.
As far as I know, the `Remote URL` can only be modified through cascading of option.
My idea was to store `username` and `password` inside the [Key Storage](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/key-storage/key-storage.html#storage-plugins) and load it to an option through providing the `storage path`. The resulting URL would look like the following: 
`https://${option.username.value}:${option.password.value}@api.local/get-environment`

**But now the problem:** 
The value of the `Storage Path` acts like a default value.
[image]

This means, that the value of the storage path is only inserted inside the option,
if no other value is provided. When opening the job, the option `username` and `password` were empty and therefore, the `cascading of option` does not work to fill in the needed values for the API URL.

Has anyone another idea of how to handle `username` and `password` inside the `Remote URL`?

Comment: Hi Pattrick! The best way to do that is to create a custom option plugin, https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/12-option-values-plugins.html#option-values-plugins also asked here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67440147/10426011

Comment: Hi @MegaDrive68k, we have many cases to load data from external sources. Creating an `Option Values Plugins` for each use case would be tedious. There is already a GitHub Issue (https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/7091) asking for the same but no response until now.

Comment: Hey Pattrick, I see, by default isn't possible right now but sounds good for an enhancement request.

Comment: @MegaDrive68k might do you know if the `Option Values Plugins (Script Plugin Type)` is possible to access environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by `MegaDrive68k`, I created a custom option plugin (Script Plugin Type). 
Unfortunately, the [Rundeck Script Plugin Type documentation](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/12-option-values-plugins.html#script-plugin-type) is not really helpful. 
With the help of the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rundeck/docs/issues/218) and the [Rundeck Script Plugin Development](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/01-plugin-development.html#script-plugin-development), I managed to finally create one.

**Actions performed:**

1. Enable the use of custom plugins (`rundeck.feature.option-values-plugin.enabled=true`) as described [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/12-option-values-plugins.html#about).
2. Create the custom option plugin (Script Plugin Type)

`custom-rundeck-option-plugin.zip` [structure](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/01-plugin-development.html#script-plugin-development):

```
custom-rundeck-option-plugin
├── contents
│   └── get_option_value.py
└── plugin.yaml
```

Content of [`plugin.yaml`](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/01-plugin-development.html#script-plugin-development):

```yaml
name: Custom Rundeck option plugin
version: 1
rundeckPluginVersion: 1.2
author: Patrick
date: 2022-07-27
providers:
  - name: Username
    service: OptionValues
    plugin-type: script
    script-interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    script-file: get_option_value.py
    script-args: USERNAME
  - name: Password
    service: OptionValues
    plugin-type: script
    script-interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    script-file: get_option_value.py
    script-args: PASSWORD
  - name: Url
    service: OptionValues
    plugin-type: script
    script-interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    script-file: get_option_value.py
    script-args: URL
```

Content of [`get_option_value.py`](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/12-option-values-plugins.html#script-plugin-type):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import sys

env_var_name = sys.argv[1]
env_var_value = os.getenv(env_var_name, f"Environment variable '{env_var_name}' not defined!")

print("==START_OPTIONS==")
print(f"{env_var_value}:{env_var_value}")
print("==END_OPTIONS==")
```

3. [Upload](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/01-plugin-development.html#plugin-development) `custom-rundeck-option-plugin.zip` to `$RDECK_BASE/libext`

Now I have the following three "options" inside the `Allowed values`:
[image]