# Inject Key Storage Password into Option's ValuesUrl

Tags: parameter-passing, rundeck

I'm trying to request a raw file from a Gitlab repository as a values JSON file for my job option. The only way so far that I managed to do it is by writing my secret token as plain text in the request URL:

https://mycompanygitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXX/repository/files/path%2Fto%2Fmy%2Ffile.json/raw?ref=main&private_token=MyV3ry53cr3Tt0k3n

I've tried using `option cascading`; I created a Secure password Input Option called `gitlab_token` which points to a `Key Storage Password` and tried every possible notation (with or without `.value`, quoted or unquoted option) in the valuesUrl field of the second option, instead of the plain token, but I keep receiving this error message pointing an invalid char at the position of the dollar sign:
[image: error_message]

*I've redacted sensitive info and edited the error print accordingly*

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72086284/cascading-remote-option-values-with-key-storage-values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your issue. It works using a text option, you can use the value in this way: `${option.mytoken.value}`.

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: e4f114d5-b3af-44a5-936f-81d984797481
  loglevel: INFO
  name: ResultData
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - name: mytoken
    value: deda66698444
  - name: apiendpoint
    valuesUrl: https://mocki.io/v1/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-${option.mytoken.value}
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: echo ${option.mytoken}
    - exec: echo ${option.apiendpoint}
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: e4f114d5-b3af-44a5-936f-81d984797481
```

Another workaround (if you don't want to use a plain text option) could be to pass the secure option to an inline script and manage the logic from there.

Please open a new issue [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues).