# RunDeck: Key Storage secrets at Custom Option Plugin

Tags: rundeck

Doesn't RunDeck support Key Storage access at custom plugin OptionValues level?

RunDeck provides ability to develop custom plugin for option at workflow.
With ["help"](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/12-option-values-plugins.html#option-values-plugins) of official docs and [help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72086284/cascading-remote-option-values-with-key-storage-values/72772050#72772050) of other stackoverflower's  post the plugin has been develop.
What I do struggle with is to remove secrets from plugin code into Key Storage. Despite's all attempts plugin doesn't render\get secrete from Key Storage.

Here is a simplified plugin code

```yaml
name: Custom Rundeck option plugin
version: 1
rundeckPluginVersion: 1.2
author: Sergii Nosko
date: 2024-02-23
providers:
  - name: Zabbix HostGroup
    service: OptionValues
    plugin-type: script
    script-interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    script-file: get_zabbix_hostgroups.py
    script-args: ${config.zabbix_url} ${config.zabbix_token}
    config:
      - name: zabbix_url
        type: Select
        title: Zabbix URL
        description: Provide a predefined list of Zabbix servers
        values: "zabbix-frontend:8080"
        default: "zabbix-frontend:8080"
      - name: zabbix_token
        type: String
        title: Zabbix API token
        description: Securely pass zabbix API token to the script
        required: false
        renderingOptions:
          selectionAccessor: "STORAGE_PATH"
          valueConversion: "STORAGE_PATH_AUTOMATIC_READ"
          storage-path-root: "keys/project/Zabbix/zabbix_token"
```

The idea is simple - feed script with zabbix url and token and obtain available hostgroups from zabbix API.

Here is a debug logs from get_zabbix_hostgroups.py to review what env variables and args are:

```
18:09:07,921 root INFO Running Debug
18:09:07,924 root INFO RD_PLUGIN_SCRIPTFILE: /home/rundeck/libext/cache/zabbix-hostgroup-option-plugin/get_zabbix_hostgroups.py
18:09:07,924 root INFO RD_CONFIG_ZABBIX_URL: zabbix-frontend:8080
18:09:07,925 root INFO RD_PLUGIN_FILE: /home/rundeck/libext/zabbix-hostgroup-option-plugin.zip
18:09:07,925 root INFO RD_PLUGIN_BASE: /home/rundeck/libext/cache/zabbix-hostgroup-option-plugin
18:09:07,925 root INFO LC_CTYPE: C.UTF-8
18:09:07,925 root INFO zabbix_url value:
18:09:07,925 root INFO zabbix-frontend:8080
18:09:07,925 root INFO zabbix_api_token value:
18:09:07,926 root INFO '${config.zabbix_token}'
18:09:07,926 zabbix_utils.api DEBUG Executing apiinfo.version method
```

So the first arg - zabbix_url works well and  is passed as expected but second zabbix_token shows just ${config.zabbix_token}

Official documentation doesn't provide much and what I left is to poke around available options and ACL.

Comment: one step forward, apparently I realised however we specify Zabbix_token, we never assign value for it, so I tried to assign value by adding values: and default: keys.  default key works and now I see value of default key passed to the script. Nevertheless seems STORAGE_PATH_AUTOMATIC_READ does't work at custom option plugins