# RUNDECK - Bearer Token authentication for Remote URL option

Tags: bearer-token, rundeck

I am using Remote URL option which reaches out to remote web server to retrieve needed data in json. The URL requires token authentication and I cannot find a way in [rundeck docs option model provider](https://docs.rundeck.com/3.3.5/manual/job-options.html#option-model-provider) on how this can be provided. Since we log requests we do not want to add the token in the URL anywhere.

1. Is there any other way this can be achieved?
2. I also noticed the [configuration docs](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#configuration) in this page has a way of providing it but my UI does not have that. What is the difference between the two?
   Thanks in advance

I tried adding a Secure Remote Authentication containing my token but that didnt do anything. I also referred to [rundeck-remote-url-option-to-https-with-basic-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74104602/rundeck-remote-url-option-to-https-with-basic-auth) and [basic-auth-with-remote-url-option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67436530/basic-auth-with-remote-url-option) but both are for basic auth and requires passing param in URL

Answer (score 0):

Since the 4.12 version, Rundeck remote options support three auth methods:

- Basic (user and password).
- API (specifying the app/server key that accepts a value provided on the key storage in two ways: via HTTP header or Query Parameter, similar to using "?key=value" in the URL).
- Bearer Token saved on the Rundeck Key Storage.

You can't see those auth methods because you're using Rundeck 4.11 or earlier (which supports direct JSON remote options), the current Rundeck version is 5.1.0. Update and test the closer method that you need, if your app/server uses a different auth method, you need a custom plugin.

Also, consider that Rundeck only "understands" [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#json-format) JSON format.

Comment: That makes sense. We are using 3.3.5 version. Thank you